# How to load page elements one after another in html

Tags: html

I want to load two elements of a page in different time.Here's my code:

```
<html>
<body >
<div style="background-image: url(im.jpg); height: 400px; width: 400px;">
<div class="test1">
test1
</div>
<div class="test2">
test2
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here,I want to load the page with background image and test1 text first,then after a moment I want to load the 2nd text test2.How can I specify this loading time?

Comment: You're gonna need Javascript / JQuery I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the element hidden from start, then you can use a timer in Javascript to show it.

Add an id to the element so that you can easily find it from the script:

```
<div class="test2" id="test2">
```

In your `<head>` tag (which is missing in the page, it goes before the `<body>` tag) you can add a style that hides the element:

```
<style>
#test2 { display: none; }
</style>
```

Then you can add a script to the `<head>` tag that will show the element after for example two seconds:

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
  window.setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById('test2').style.display = 'block';
  }, 2000);
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/q2VJ4/

```
@keyframes dropHeader {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  99%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes dropHeader {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  99%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}

.test2 {
  -moz-animation-name: dropHeader;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
-moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
-moz-animation-duration: 3s;

-webkit-animation-name: dropHeader;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
-webkit-animation-duration: 3s;

animation-name: dropHeader;
animation-iteration-count: 1;
animation-timing-function: ease-in;
animation-duration: 3s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with jquery with the hide show option http://api.jquery.com/show/

```
<div id="clickme">
  Click here
</div>
<img id="book" src="book.png" alt="" width="100" height="123">
With the element initially hidden, we can show it slowly:
$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
  $( "#book" ).show( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you:
Loads the first element, then loads the second element.

http://jsfiddle.net/azRwq/2/

**Using jQuery** (make sure to include the script / src in your html)
Loads the first one after 2 second, and loads the second one after 4 seconds.:

```
$( "#test1" ).hide();
$( "#test2" ).hide();

setTimeout(function(){
    $( "#test1" ).show();
}, 2000);

setTimeout(function(){
    $( "#test2" ).show();
}, 4000);
```

**HTML**:

```
<div id="test1" style="background: red;">
    <p>test1</p>
</div>

<div id="test2" style="background: blue;">
    <p>test2</p>
</div>
```

Another option would be to remove remove:

```
$( "#test1" ).hide();
$( "#test2" ).hide();
```

and use `display:none;` in the css for each element